# Redirigir a una url en php de acuerdo con el id

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

Tengo dos páginas. Una llamada "myprofile.php" y otra "userprofile.php". Actualmente logré que cuando el usuario cliquee en un enlace, sea capaz de acceder a "myprofile.php" de acuerdo con su ID de usuario y no al de otros usuarios, y a la vez que al acceder a "userprofile.php" pueda acceder a cada perfil de usuario, es decir, que haya un único perfil para cada usuario registrado en el sitio de acuerdo a su ID. Mi problema es que necesito lograr que cuando un usuario cliquee para ir a userprofile.php y el ID de este usuario coincida con el indicado en este mismo enlace, no lo redirija a su perfil de usuario público (que es lo que verían los demás usuarios) si no justamente a su página de "myprofile.php". Adjunto el código que tengo hasta el momento y que no logré hacer que cumpla esta función.

**myprofile.php**

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<?php

session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        include_once 'includes/templates/headeraccess.php';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
    }else{
        include_once 'includes/templates/headerlogged.php';
    }

    include 'php/conexion_be.php';
    
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], (FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));

        $myuser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id' ");
        $use = mysqli_fetch_array($myuser);

        if($_SESSION['id'] != $id) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","No deberías estar en esta página","error").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
        }
    }

?>
```

**userprofile.php**

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<?php
    include 'php/conexion_be.php';  
    $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], (FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
    $myuser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $use = mysqli_fetch_array($myuser);
    if($_SESSION['id'] = $id){
        header("location: myprofile.php");
    }else{
        header("location: userprofile.php");
    }
?>
<?php
session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        include_once 'includes/templates/headeraccess.php';
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("Ups!","Debes iniciar sesión para estar aquí.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'registro.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        session_destroy();
        die();
    }else{
        include_once 'includes/templates/headerlogged.php';
    }
?>
```

Y accedo a estas páginas mediante un  de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="userprofile.php?id=<?php echo $use['id'];?>">Ver perfil</a>
<li><a href="myprofile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];?>">Mi Cuenta</a></li>
```

Lo que conseguí actualmente es que efectivamente al cliquear sobre el enlace "Ver perfil" me redirija hacia myprofile.php pero siempre, es decir, no cuando el userprofile.php?id= coincide con el id del usuario que está logueado, sino en todo momento. Debería cambiar eso para que funcione como especifiqué al inicio. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios errores en tu código. Para empezar, para poder utilizar el arreglo `$_SESSION`, tienes que llamar a la función `session_start()` **antes**. Es por eso que, al momento de hacer el if y tratar de comparar `$_SESSION['id']` con `$id`, este te arroja un resultado incorrecto, debido a que la sesión no está iniciada.

Para solucionar esto, podrías llamar a la función `session_start()` al principio de tu código PHP, como muestra este ejemplo:

```
<?php
session_start(); // Lo pones aquí, antes de obtener el $_SESSION['id']
include 'php/conexion_be.php';  
$id = filter_var($_GET['id'], (FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT));
...
```

Recuerda llamar a esta función sólo una vez.

Además de eso, cuando verificas si el id de la sesión es igual al id del usuario, usaste un sólo signo igual (=). Aquí, para poder hacer una comparación, tienes que usar dos signos iguales (==) y así la expresión te retorna un valor booleano (true o false):

```
if($_SESSION['id'] == $id){ // Doble igual == para que retorne true o false
    header("location: myprofile.php");
}else{
    header("location: userprofile.php");
}
```

Ahora, además de estos dos cambios, puede que el if esté mal diseñado. Si el id es igual que el id que está en la sesión, te llevará a `myprofile.php` como bien está haciendo ahora, pero si no, te llevará nuevamente a la página `userprofile.php` y volverá a ejecutarse el mismo código pudiendo causar un **loop de redirección**.

```
if($_SESSION['id'] == $id){
    header("location: myprofile.php");
}
// Sin else, solo deja que siga ejecutándose el código de la página actual.
```

Tabmién te recomiendo usar `exit()` o `die()` después de redirigir con `header("location: myprofile.php")` para que se detenga la ejecución del código y no cause problemas inesperados:

```
if($_SESSION['id'] == $id){
    header("location: myprofile.php");
    exit(); // o die()
}
```

Prueba con estos cambios y ve si ahora funciona bien tu código.

Comment: Funcionó!!!! Muchisimas gracias, en serio! Te realizo una utlima consulta, tienes idea como puedo hacer para que en el header me redirija al "myprofile.php" pero con el id de la sesion? es decir quisiera que redirija a "myprofile.php?id=<y aqui el id del usuario logueado>"

Comment: Sólo agrégalo al final del myprofile al momento de hacer la redirección  `header("location: myprofile.php?id=<ID DEL USUARIO>");`